# to wrap or not to wrap ESAPI

Tags: java, maintainability, decoupling, esapi

We have several webapps that needs functionality provided by ESAPI java library. my colleague and I are in a dilemma whether to use ESAPI directly thereby creating a direct dependence on ESAPI or create an interface that abstracts calls to ESAPI.

By abstracting a dependence on a library we get flexibility to easily switch to some other option if need arises. Besides that we get to define our own interface which is more likely to match our needs.

But as we identify methods that we need in our interface, it is looking more and more like interfaces used in ESAPI itself. And ESAPI is a facade itself, with configurable implementations of Validator, Encryptor and others.

Is ESAPI mature enough that it is safe to directly depend on it or is it wise to stick with this wrapper ?

Comment: Yeah, this is really an opinion-based kind of question.  There's been some talk about where ESAPI needs to go, I personally think it tries to do too much... instead of a one-stop shop they should break it up into smaller libraries that you then import as needed.  I don't know that the interfaces they define are likely to change terribly much (not like encoding/decoding can change much) but if I were to start a brand new approach I would use an adapter pattern like what you're doing.  OWASP stripped ESAPI of its flagship status a short while ago.

Comment: getting answers from esapi contributors. looks like progress is stalled due to lack of volunteers. and 3.0 will likely be very different than 2.0. will stick with wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, while I agree in principle with whole "ESAPI is supposed to ***be*** the wrapper" mantra, I think that you always need to consider broader issues. First and foremost, it probably depends on how much of ESAPI you intend to use and how widely dispersed across your source code it might get deployed. If you are only going to use a small portion of it in some isolated code somewhere, there probably is no point in wrapping it with another layer because it would be relative simple to change should the need arise. On the other hand, if you are at the other extreme, it might be a good idea to protect your investment and isolate it from any future changes. (For example, the proposed ESAPI 3 (see https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java) is planned to have very different interfaces.)

Lastly, while it pains me to say it, ESAPI support has not been great as of late. There has only been myself and one other person even contributing to it at all over the past 2-3 years. In fact, while it's not a done deal, ESAPI will very likely lose its OWASP "flagship" status (see http://off-the-wall-security.blogspot.com/2014/03/esapi-no-longer-owasp-flagship-project.html). There has even been talk of marking the project as "sunset" unless we start getting more volunteers. If all you want to use ESAPI for is exclusively output encoding and data validation, then I would encourage you to look at the OWASP Java Encoder Project and the OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer Project. (Sorry, I don't have links handy, but I'm sure you know how to use search engines just as well as I.)

-kevin wall / ESAPI Java project lead

Comment: thanks. I like static access to all functionality via ESAPI locator. hope to see renewed interest in the project

Answer (score 1):

The goal of ESAPI is to **be** the wrapper, allowing you to swap in components as you see fit. In it's current release incarnation this is simply not a viable approach however as ESAPI has a huge footprint and frankly most people are only using a very small part of the ESAPI.

That being said, ESAPI 3.0 aims to solve this problem but we (The ESAPI Team) have had a hard time getting community involvement in working on the new stuff. You can check out the github repository for ESAPI 3.0 which aims to solve the problems described here in the comments and shift the focus back to being the API that provides all your security controls rather than trying to be the security controls itself.

Github: https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is some kind of oppinion based.

But I use ESAPI since one or two years (only for output-escaping) and had no problems using this library directly.

I use the escape methods in an XSL stylesheet, so I made a wrapper, but only for a better access, than for encapsulation.

If **you** have a better feeling about extracting it behind an interface, yust do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is ESAPI mature enough that it is safe to directly depend on it or is it wise to stick with this wrapper ?

My story is that we have been using `ESAPI` (only canonicalization before stripping out various injection character patterns from input string typed by users in html forms) since two years, depending directly on its interface and without any problems.

Such a little dependency is implemented in a single java class (invoked from a servlet filter): if the interface changes, we'll have to change only few lines of code in that class. So at the moment a wrapping interface wouldn't give us any advantages on current implementation.

I suggest to assess the maturity of the project by looking at other sources such as http://www.ohloh.net/p/owasp-esapi-java or asking to the ESAPI community directly.